# check if token (on pandas column) is in an external list of trigrams

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a dataframe whith a column "token" that has a single word extracted by several texts, for example:

```
text =  "hello it's me"


df['token'] 

0  hello
1  it
2  '
3  s
4  me
```

the dataframe is very long because I have 1000 sentences, and all are splitted and divided like I wrote above.
Now I have a list of trigrams, like `['no way out', 'my life is', 'hello my name']`
I want to check if those sentences start with one of the trigram in the list, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a much better data structure for the tokens is a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). By defining a set from `df.token`, you can reduce the lookup complexity to `O(1)`, and since you only need to iterate over the list of sentences, this leaves us with a `O(len(l))` approach:

```
tokens = set(df.token.values.tolist())
l = ['no way out', 'my life is', 'hello my name']

[i.split(maxsplit=1)[0] in tokens for i in l]
# [False, False, True]
```